# SwiftUi scaling text differently on device

Tags: swiftui

I'm using the following code to display a large number on screen using SwiftUI:

```swift
return GeometryReader() { geometry in
            Text(series.split(separator: ",")[self.calculator.pointsIndex])
                .font(Font.system(size: round(geometry.size.height * 1.5),
                                  weight: .light,
                                  design: .rounded))
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.2)
                .scaledToFit()
                .allowsTightening(true)
                .background(Color.red.opacity(0.25))
        }
```

On the simulator it looks like this:

[image]

On the device it looks like this:

[image]

I've been racking my head trying to work out why the number is so much smaller on device. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This `round(geometry.size.height * UIScreen.main.scale * 1.2` gives different results on a device (and different devices) and simulator.

I prefer to use the following combination when need text scaled to available parent space

```
      Text("any text here")
        .font(.system(size: 1000))
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.01)
        .lineLimit(1)
```

so you can try the following modified your code

```swift
return GeometryReader { _ in // just to consume all available space
            Text(series.split(separator: ",")[self.calculator.pointsIndex])
                .font(.system(size: 1000, weight: .light, design: .rounded))
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.01)
                .lineLimit(1)
                .background(Color.red.opacity(0.25))
        }
```

Comment: Oh, sorry. That line was originally `.font(Font.system(size: round(geometry.size.height * 1.5), weight: .light, design: .rounded))`. The `UIScreen` bit was me trying to figure out what was going on :-) I'll correct my code.